# gitlab-ci ssh remote to server error Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app

Tags: git, docker, ssh, gitlab-ci, digital-ocean

error Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

image: ubuntu

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -

- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh
- ssh-keyscan ${ip_address}  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Test SSH:
  script:
  - ssh user@ip "cd blog && git pull && docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer install && cp .env.example .env && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d && docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate"